# Dagesh in Ne'umecha

Tags: grammar-dikduk, bircas-krias-shema

Most nouns with a pronoun suffix and end with a short vowel have a *dagesh chazak* added. Examples: עַמִּי, כֻּלּוֹ, בָּתֵּינוּ. However, the word כִּנְאֻמֶךָ (in Emes Veyatziv) does not have a *dagesh* in the *mem*. Why not?

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: The dagesh chazak in bateinu is an exception dagesh. No rules should be learned from there.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why might this not be on topic?

Comment: Hebrew language is not a reason for a question to be on topic.

Comment: @DoubleAA Language of prayers is

Comment: @IsaacMoses ...as it relates to prayers. A word's existing in a prayer doesn't make it on topic either.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the question is about the word in the context of the prayer, not just a word that happens to also be in a prayer

Comment: @IsaacMoses I'm not so sure. In what way does the context of prayer influence/show-itself/affect the question

Comment: @DoubleAA It's relevant because it affects how the word is pronounced in this case.

Comment: @Daniel The davening affects how the word is pronounced? How does it do that?

Comment: @DoubleAA the dagesh affects how the word is pronounced which is relevant to davenng.